# Django email contact me form

Tags: django, email, sendgrid, yahoo

So I'm working on this django web app and I want to create a contact me form for my client. My client wants the users of his website to be able to send him emails directly from the form available on the platform. But my client uses a free yahoo email address.

I'm kind of confused of where to begin. But here is my suggested approach see if you can give me an advice:

1- create a form in the forms.py with the different fields of the form.

2 - link the form to the template.

3- create the view for the contact form.

4- add the path in the url pattern.

I read an article that says I need to go through an email service like SendGrid to actually send an email. But it said that I need a professional account to be able to do it.

I really appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to go looks good.

You do not need any sending service, as long as you have a proper SMTP account to use for sending.

Just add the SMTP credentials to your `settings.py` and you can use the django core functions to send email messages.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#smtp-backend

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I highly appreciate the attention you brought towards my inquiry.